# Diesel engine struggling to start when cold

Tags: starting, diesel, cold-start, fuel-injectors

I have a 2.7D `Ford AJD-V6/PSA DT17` diesel engine, on which I recently replaced 3 fuel injectors (all 3 of them were leaking). After the injectors were replaced, I now encounter the following problem:

On cold starts (when I first start the engine, in the morning, outside temperature 0 degrees Celsius), it needs to crank a couple of times (6-7-8) before it starts.

I didn't had this problem before changing the injectors, it was always starting in about 2-3 cranks.

There's a video demonstrating the problem:

[Jaguar S-Type 2.7D hard cold start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm4in-bCmAs)

Could this be because of the 3 injectors that were replaced? May they be worn or clogged? I'm asking this because when I immediately stop the engine (after the initial cold start), and start it again, the second start is much more faster (as you can see in video). If the injectors were the problem, wouldn't the second start also be hard? (since the engine is still cold).

Comment: Have you checked the heater plugs? I have an x-type and it started fine this morning at -10 degrees... Yesterday it took 3 goes... but no real issue. Have you considered asking this on the Jaguar Forum (www.jaguarforum.com), the people there only concern themselves with jag and are really helpful...